# Response text content as file

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am going to create an api to export contacts from db to csv file.

I want to fetch each chunk then write to the response file like this.

```
set response header to application/csv

while has next chunk
  content = fetch next chunk
  write content to response stream
```

I've done it before using Spring framework but couldn't find a way to solve it with HapiJs.

Comment: So what's your question and what have you tried?

Comment: Don't know how to try. There is no hint to get started :(